# How to create a private subnet within my current VPC?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc

I have a VPC with 6 public subnet, I need to create a private one to deploy a lambda function that needs to connect to a DB, no need to have internet access.

The problem is that when I try to create a new one, it comes with an internet gateway attached to it.

How can I create a simple private subnet?

Comment: You have to describe step by step how do you create such a subnet.

Comment: this is actually what I am asking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What makes a public subnet "public" is having a route table with a route to an internet gateway (IGW). Thus, any subnet which does not have such a route, is "private" by definition.

In your case, probably your subnet is using a vpc's [main route table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Route_Tables.html), which has the route to IGW. In that case, create a new route table (by default it will not have a route to IGW) and [associate it with](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/WorkWithRouteTables.html#ChangeRouteTable) the new subnet.

This way your new subnet will use the new route table without IGW, and will be "private".